# How to connect Hyperspec documentation to Emacs SLIME on MS Windows

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime

With this minimal init file:

```
(setq package-load-list '((slime t)))
(setq inferior-lisp-program "clisp")
(package-initialize)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(require 'slime)
(slime-setup)
(slime)
(find-file "~/t/del.lisp")
```

Everything seems to work, such as slime-eval-defun and slime-complete-symbol, except for looking up documentation. M-x slime-describe-symbol RET print RET results in this error:

```
CLHS-ROOT: variable *CLHS-ROOT-DEFAULT* has no value
```

What do I need to add in my init file to make it work?

I also tried downloading the hyperspec tar file and extracting it to a directory, and this code:

```
(setq package-load-list '((slime t)))
(setq inferior-lisp-program "clisp"
      common-lisp-hyperspec-root "c:/run/HyperSpec/"
      common-lisp-hyperspec-symbol-table "c:/run/HyperSpec/Data/Map_Sym.txt")
(package-initialize)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(require 'slime)
(slime-setup)
(slime)
(find-file "~/t/del.lisp")
```

That doesn't work either. I do not know if the bug is in that init file, or in the SLIME version I am using, because this is my first time with SLIME.

Versions:

- MS Windows 7
- Emacs version 24.3.1 (probably latest stable)
- SLIME version 20130626.1151  (latest from MELPA) (One from Marmalade says it can't compile nil, I don't know what that means and so I am using one from MELPA instead)
- GNU CLISP 2.49 (latest stable)

*UPDATE*

`C-c C-d f RET print RET` works fine. This is bound to `slime-describe-function`, which is undocumented, and not listed in SLIME menu. There is also `slime-documentation-lookup` which is bound to `C-c C-d C-d` which can open documentation for variables (not just functions) in a browser, and that works too. Looks like only `slime-describe-symbol doesn't work.

Answer (score 9):

I haven't done it on Windows, but if I were you, I'd try to do this with Quicklisp: `(ql:quickload "clhs")` and follow the printed directions.

I'd also get SLIME from Quicklisp via `(ql:quickload "quicklisp-slime-helper")`, but if your slime works ok, no real need.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that SLIME is installed from an emacs package archive (preferably MELPA) (and that GNU CLISP is installed), here is combination of relevant portions from [How to install Common Lisp and SLIME on MS Windows](http://yoo2080.wordpress.com/2013/08/18/how-to-install-common-lisp-and-slime-on-ms-windows/):

Assuming starting from scratch after commenting out any SLIME customization code you already have, start by putting the following code to your init file which should be evaluated after `package-initialize`:

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "clisp")
(setq slime-auto-connect 'ask)

(defun my-slime-setup ()
  (require 'slime)
  (slime-setup))
(defvar my--slime-setup-done nil)
(defun my-slime-setup-once ()
  (unless my--slime-setup-done
    (my-slime-setup)
    (setq my--slime-setup-done t)))
(defadvice lisp-mode (before my-slime-setup-once activate)
  (my-slime-setup-once))
```

What that does is defining my-slime-setup and make sure the function runs just once if you are using SLIME that day. my-slime-setup is also a container to which you can add your own SLIME customization code.

Now to connect the downloaded documentation to SLIME, extract the downloaded archive and you will get a folder with name `Hyperspec`, and then you move that folder to the Emacs bin directory, or its parent directory, or its grandparent directory, Put the following code in Emacs init file.

```
(defun my-hyperspec-setup ()
  (let ((dir (locate-dominating-file invocation-directory "HyperSpec/")))
    (if dir
        (progn
          (setq common-lisp-hyperspec-root (expand-file-name "HyperSpec/" dir)))
      (warn "No HyperSpec directory found"))))
```

and add `my-hyperspec-setup` to  `my-slime-setup` like this:

```
(defun my-slime-setup ()
  (my-hyperspec-setup)
  (require 'slime)
  (slime-setup))
```

and restart Emacs.

And now when you do `M-x slime-describe-symbol RET print RET` in a lisp buffer, it should show the description of PRINT in another buffer.

I should confess that I am sourcing from my own article and also answering my own question after about 8 months. The answer is tested with latest SLIME from MELPA and on a vanilla GNU Emacs.